# how to repeat the slideshow if it reach the end in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I created a flexbox carousel, when the arrows being clicked they go margin right or left 200px on every click.

I am trying to make a loop, when it reaches the end, it restarts with the first "item" again.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.next-button').on('click', function(){
    $('.carousel-item').animate({"margin-left": "-=200px"}, 200);
  });
  $('.prev-button').on('click', function(){
    $('.carousel-item').animate({"margin-left": "+=200px"}, 200);
  });
});
```

```css
.carousel-container {
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 40px 20px;
  
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:auto;
  padding:0;
  
  border: 1px solid red;
  align-items: center;
  
}

.carousel-item {
  height: 100%;
  margin:5px;
  margin-left:-200px;
  padding:0;
  
  -moz-box-orient:horizontal;
  -ms-box-orient:horizontal;
  -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
  -o-box-orient:horizontal;
  box-orient:horizontal;

  display:-moz-box;
  display:-ms-box;
  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-o-box;
  display:box;
    
  list-style-type:none;
}

.item {
  border:solid 1px #333;
  margin-right:10px;
  width:250px;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.item > a {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.prev-button, .next-button {
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: gray;
}

.navigation {
  width: 60px;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.next-button:hover, .prev-button:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.navigation:active {
  color: white;
}

.next-button {
  right:0;
}

.prev-button {
  left: 0;
}

/* .carousel-item li:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url('http://urbanphenomena.net/imgs/cover/bq2.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
} */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-container">
  <a class="prev-button navigation" href="#"><</a>
  &nbsp;
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <li class="item"><a href="#"> 1 </a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#"> 2 </a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#"> 3 </a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#"> 4 </a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#"> 5 </a></li>
    
    <li class="item"><a href="#"> 6 </a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#"> 7 </a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#"> 8 </a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#"> 9 </a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#">  </a></li>
  </div>
  &nbsp;
  <a class="next-button navigation" href="#">></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Custom slider, using the new CSS grid system: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: I'd just recommend using a 3rd party plugin for this because you need to write JavaScript functions to clone the list items for a "faux" looping effect.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var marginLeft = 0;

  $('.next-button').on('click', function() {
    if (Math.abs(marginLeft) < (200) * ($('li').length)) {
      marginLeft -= 200;
      $('.carousel-item').animate({
        "margin-left": "-=200px"
      }, 200);
    } else {
      //reset
      marginLeft = 0;
      $('.carousel-item').animate({
        "margin-left": "0"
      }, 200);
    }
  });
  $('.prev-button').on('click', function() {
    if (Math.abs(marginLeft) > (200) * ($('li').length)) {
      marginLeft = (200) * ($('li').length);
      $('.carousel-item').animate({
        "margin-left": marginLeft + "px"
      }, 200);

    } else {
      marginLeft -= 200;
      $('.carousel-item').animate({
        "margin-left": marginLeft + "px"
      }, 200);

    }
  });
});
```

This may not be the exact solution to your question but an idea as to how you may calculate how much left/right has your div already animated and apply some logic to reset those values according to your need.

Comment: Almost like what I want, but when it reaches the end, I want it to continue sliding and make slide 1 as the next slide, something like this: http://www.andismith.com/flexbox-carousel/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.next-button').on('click', function() {
    if (parseInt($('.carousel-item').css("margin-left").slice(0, -2)) < -2000) {
      $('.carousel-item').animate({
        "margin-left": "0px"
      }, 200)
    } else {
      $('.carousel-item').animate({
        "margin-left": "-=200px"
      }, 200);
    }
  });


  $('.prev-button').on('click', function() {
    if (parseInt($('.carousel-item').css("margin-left").slice(0, -2)) > 0) {
      $('.carousel-item').animate({
        "margin-left": "-2000px"
      }, 200)
    } else {
      $('.carousel-item').animate({
        "margin-left": "+=200px"
      }, 200);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.carousel-container {
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 40px 20px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  align-items: center;
}

.carousel-item {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -o-box-orient: horizontal;
  box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -o-box;
  display: box;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.item {
  border: solid 1px #333;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.item>a {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.prev-button,
.next-button {
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: gray;
}

.navigation {
  width: 60px;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.next-button:hover,
.prev-button:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.navigation:active {
  color: white;
}

.next-button {
  right: 0;
}

.prev-button {
  left: 0;
}


/* .carousel-item li:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url('http://urbanphenomena.net/imgs/cover/bq2.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
} */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-container">
  <a class="prev-button navigation" href="#">
    <</a>
      &nbsp;
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <li class="item"><a href="#"> 1 </a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#"> 2 </a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#"> 3 </a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#"> 4 </a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#"> 5 </a></li>

        <li class="item"><a href="#"> 6 </a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#"> 7 </a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#"> 8 </a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#"> 9 </a></li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="#"> </a>
        </li>
      </div>
      &nbsp;
      <a class="next-button navigation" href="#">></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to get the margin-left of the carousel-item then with if/else statement control your animation

```
 var margin-left=('.carousel-item').css("marginLeft");
```

Comment: So after you get the value of the left margin, then what? He want's it looped not shoot to the beginning of the slides. To be able to loop, cloning will need to take place.

Comment: Then with animate and with the value he continues the code it will work if he makes a right logarithm and know what to do then